# Convergence of solutions to parametrized ODE when no limiting ODE exists

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

There is plenty of literature on the convergence of the solutions to the real ODE, parametrized by $N \in (0;\infty)$,
\begin{equation}
f_N' (x)
=
a_N (x) \cdot f_N (x)
+ b_N (x)
\end{equation}
to the solution of the ODE
\begin{equation}
f_\infty' (x)
=
a_\infty (x) \cdot f_\infty (x)
+ b_\infty (x),
\end{equation}
provided that $a_N \to a_\infty$ and $b_N \to b_\infty$ as $N \to \infty$ in some sense. For instance: [Kodlyuk, T. I., V. A. Mikhailets, and N. V. Reva. "Limit theorems for one-dimensional boundary-value problems." Ukrainian Mathematical Journal 65 (2013): 77-90.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11253-013-0766-x)

**Question:** Is there also any literature addressing the asymptotic behaviour of $f_N$ as $N \to \infty$ in the case **when no limiting ODE exists**? Any reference is appreciated.

I am particularly (but not only!) interested in the limit of $N \cdot f_N$ in the case that when $a_N(x) = N \cdot \tilde a_N(x)$ and $\tilde a_N(x)$ converges to some $\tilde a_\infty(x) \ge \varepsilon > 0$ as $N \to \infty$. Then $a_\infty$ would be infinity.

**Very simple example**: The solution to
\begin{equation}
f_N' (x)
=
- N \cdot f_N (x)
+ b
=
- N \bigg(
f_N (x)
- \frac b N
\bigg)
\end{equation}
is
\begin{equation}
f_N(x)
=
\exp(-N x + C)
+ \frac b N.
\end{equation}
Then for all $x > 0$, it holds
\begin{equation}
\lim_{N\to \infty} N \cdot f_N(x) = b.
\end{equation}
At least heuristically, under some regularity assumptions, this can also be easily argued not having looked at the explicit solution: Due to the feedback in the ODE, for large $N$, $f$ will tend to an "equilibrium" where $f_N(x)-  b/N = 0$, as $x$ growths. Therefore, I suppose that people have already looked onto problems of similar kind.

Answer (score 4):

These are called singular limits and you need  to deal with them on a case by case basis.  They're tricky. Your very simple example can be reduced to a regular  limit by making the change in variables $x=\frac{t}{N}$ so
$$
\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{dt}{dx}\frac{d}{dt}= N\frac{d}{dt}. 
$$
Consider the new function
$$
g_N(t)=f_N(x)= f_N(t/N).
$$
It satisfies the  ODE
$$
\frac{dg_N}{dt}= -g_N(t)+\frac{b}{N}
$$
and now  there is a limiting ODE. The general solution of this equation is

$$ g_N(t)=C e^{-t}+\frac{b}{N}\int_0^te^{-(t-s)} ds= C e^{-t}+\frac{be^{-t}}{N}\int_0^t e^{s}ds = C e^{-t} +\frac{b}{N}(1-e^{-t}). du$$

Hence $g_N(Nt)= Ce^{-Nt}+\frac{b}{N}(1-e^{-Nt})$.

This equation is too special to draw general lessons but the above argument  works for systems of the form

$$ f'_N(x)=N Af_N(x)+b(x), $$

where $A$ is a $k\times k$ matrix whose eigenvalues have negative  real part and $b:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}^k$ is bounded and continuous.  Making the same change in coordinates we deduce

$$g_N = e^{tA} C_0+ \frac{1}{N}\int_0^t  e^{(t-s)A} b(s/n) ds=e^{tA} C_0+ \frac{1}{N}\int_0^t  e^{uA} b((t-u)/N) du, $$

where $C_0\in \mathbb{R}^k$. Then

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} Ng_N(Nt)= b(t)\int_0^\infty e^{uA}  du. $$

Comment: Should it not be $-g_N(t) + b/N$?

Comment: Even if I compute the limit of $\lim_{N \to \infty} g_N(x)$ (which seems to be the idea here?), how would this help to find the limit $\lim_{N \to \infty} N \cdot f_N(x) = \lim_{N \to \infty} N \cdot g_N(x\cdot N)$?

Comment: @Kolodez. You are correct about the sign and it is important.   As for the second question, I have updated my answer.

Comment: This multidimensional generalization looks very useful. Do you know a reference in the literature where it is used (or even introduced the first time)?

Comment: @Kolodez I made up this example myself to illustrate the usefulness of this change in coordinates.  There is no general technique. You have to take advantage of the specifics of your concrete situation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a large literature on this which goes under the names WKB or JWKB method, or Phase Integral method. It is most frequently considered for a second order linear ODE
$$y''+N^2Qy=0,$$
and gives the approximate solutions in the form
$$y=Q^{-1/4}\exp\left(\pm iN\int \sqrt{Q}\right).$$
There are infinitely many modifications and generalizations:
for higher order ODE, for PDE and for non-linear ODE/PDE.

Of course, for the first order scalar ODE this is an overshot since its exact solution can be written explicitly.

Remark. JWKB stands for Jeffreys, Kramers, Wentzel and Brillouin, though the main idea is due to Liouville.

Remark 2. For an introduction, I recommend a nice little book J. Heading, Introduction to phase-integral methods, John Wiley, NY 1962. But the existing literature on WKB-asymptotics is truly enormous.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to mainly address homogeneous ODEs. Do you also know a reference where (as simple as possible) inhomogeneous ODEs are addressed?

Comment: Solution of a non-homogeneous linear ODE is obtained from those of homogeneous ones by integration (the method of variation of constant), therefore you can derive asymptotics for them as well. As I said, the literature on this is truly enormous, and I only indicated the key result.

Comment: If you have a specific problem, I can probably give more precise directions.